# Artisan Laravel Running Alls Commands

Tags: laravel, command, laravel-artisan

I have several customs commands in my application i have make a typo in call , for showing alls to you.

[image]

If i run only day:All i have this result.

[image]

Its great my code works good and i have the result that i want but it seem to run all the other customs command that i have and i don't want that.

I want to run only the day:All not varDay or graph.

The proof of this behaviour is , if i add a dd('foo') in my graph:All command, and i run again i have this.
[image]

Anyone know a way to run only the command that i want and not make Artisan run alls?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Post your command file and show us how you've coded it.

Comment: @Sandeesh Ok it's done

Comment: Is that the actual code? It has so many syntax errors. How is it even running? Can you check the code again and also post the `graph:All` command code.

Comment: @Sandeesh I had delete all variables now you have all the code , it working perfectly.

Comment: So your issue is resolved?

Comment: @Sandeesh No this code works good since always , the problem is when i run day:All or an others is run all the commands , not only the one i want. If i put a dd('foo') in var:All and run day:All , it the same its display  'foo'.

Comment: Alright i get it. Can you share the graph:All code as well? Also the contents of `app/Console/Kernel.php`.This is not the typical behaviour of console commands.

Comment: @Sandeesh Okai i had the Kernel , i can't for graph:All it will be a really big files and i don't really want to post it on internet , i have same problem with other commands , the bug don't seem to came from graph:All

Comment: I don't see any issues with the commands being registered. Although you shouldn't write your commands like the way you do. Move all your logic to the `handle` method instead of the constructor. Like you said the issue might be associated with the other commands.

Comment: @Sandeesh Ok thanks , i gonna try see if it working.Thanks for help